# Maven compiler error - invalid flag -- release

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am getting a maven compiler error when compiling with JDK 1.8

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project DUMMY : Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]`

Here is my pom configuration for compiler plugin

```
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.release}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.release}</target>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                <jdkToolchain>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.release}</version>
                </jdkToolchain>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
            </configuration>
```

Have I configured this incorrectly? Also, this works fine when I have Java 11 for `JAVA_HOME`, but not with Java 8. Is this expected? Also, from the docs I see that `maven.compiler.release` is tied with `release` config anyway. So, does it mean I can ommit the `release` attribute below and it should be fine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) this argument supported since Java 9, so either change your JDK version or just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 fixes I applied to make it work.

Fix 1: Missed to point out to JDK11 Version in environment variables. So cross verify both User variables and System variables path

Fix 2: Even after fix 1 STS throwed same error again and again while doing mvn install. Restarted STS tool helped to reflect path. Issue got fixed